# Bidirectional port in verilog testbench

Tags: verilog

How do we assign an input to a bidirectional port in Verilog testbench ?

I have a design and an associated testbench. The relevant part of design is as follows:

```
module i2cModule (
input   wire        mod_en , 
input   wire        rec_ack ,
input   wire        burst_write , burst_read ,
input   wire        [7 : 0] data_tx ,   
output  wire        [7 : 0] data_rx ,   
output  wire        ack ,
inout   wire    scl ,
inout   wire    sda 
) ;

// Some code here

send_command :
    begin   
        case (bit_counter)          // Parallel to serial convertor
            7   : sda_reg = ( !scl) ? data_tx[7] : sda_reg ;
            6   : sda_reg = ( !scl) ? data_tx[6] : sda_reg ;
            5   : sda_reg = ( !scl) ? data_tx[5] : sda_reg ;
            4   : sda_reg = ( !scl) ? data_tx[4] : sda_reg ;
            3   : sda_reg = ( !scl) ? data_tx[3] : sda_reg ;
            2   : sda_reg = ( !scl) ? data_tx[2] : sda_reg ;
            1   : sda_reg = ( !scl) ? data_tx[1] : sda_reg ;
            0   : sda_reg = ( !scl) ? data_tx[0] : sda_reg ;
        endcase 
        start_bit_counter = (scl && !bit_counter) ? 1'b0 : start_bit_counter ;
        i2c_next = (!start_bit_counter) ? wait_ack : send_command ;
    end

    wait_ack :
    begin
        ack_reg = ( scl) ? sda : ack_reg ;
        start_bit_counter = ( scl) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0 ;
        i2c_next = (scl && !ack_reg) ? (data_tx[7] ? rx_mode : tx_mode ) : wait_ack ;
    end

// Some code here
```

Testbench is as follows:

```
module i2c_test;

// Inputs
reg mod_en;
reg rec_ack;
reg burst_write;
reg burst_read;
reg [7:0] data_tx;

// Outputs
wire [7:0] data_rx;
wire ack;

// Bidirs
wire scl;
wire sda;

// Some stimulus here ; all stimulus in initial block

    mod_en = 1 ;
    data_tx = 8'b10101010 ;             // Write mode
    repeat (8) @ (posedge scl) ;    // Wait 8 clocks for command to be sent
    sda = 1'b0 ;                                            // slave ack
    @ (posedge scl) ;
```

The design synthesizes successfully for target device. However, in testbench, when I try to drive `sda`, it gives an error. Also, if change `sda` to reg, then also it says that outputs cannot be reg type.

How do I drive `sda` in testbench?

Comment: @Qiu. In test bench. If I try to drive sda, it says "Procedural assignment to a non-register sda is not permitted" . If I change sda to reg, it says "Non-net variable cannot be connected to inout port sda" . (same error is for scl as well. scl is inout too)

Comment: You have a problem with your port connections, yet you have shown none of them

Comment: @dave_59. I'm not sure I get you. Do you mean port mapping ? I have declared all pins wire in teh design, with scl and sda as inouts.

Comment: @dave_59. I've added port declarations, if that helps.

Comment: How are you instantiating the i2cModule in your test bench?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to drive a bidir signal from another module or a test bench, you can do like this:

```
wire [7:0] input_value;
wire [7:0] bidir_signal;
reg [7:0] output_value;
reg output_value_valid;

mymodule myinstance (
  ...
  ...
  .bidir_signal(bidir_signal),
  ...
  ...
);

assign input_value = bidir_signal;
assign bidir_signal = (output_value_valid==1'b1)? output_value : 8'hZZ;

initial begin
  output_value_valid = 0;
  // use bidir_signal as input here so you can read its current value
  //
  $display ("Current value: %x\n", input_value);
  #100;
  // now we switch to output signal: we write value 10101010 in it
  output_value_valid = 1;
  output_value = 8'hAA;
  #100;
  $finish;
end
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know (as soon as I get on pc). Thanks for your response.

Comment: I think I'll manage the sda line in my design with your approach. But how do I manage the scl line ? As you might be aware, serial clock (scl) in an i2c is provided by the master. However, the slave can stretch the clock as long as it pleases, if it is not ready. So truly speaking, scl is kinda pseudo inout port. If I use tristate like in sda, it would mean that slave can provide serial clock as well. But this is not the case. (please do not remove the existing code ; add new if you wish though)

Comment: I think I should make scl just output rather than inout.. ?